# Does changing the iOS bundle display name, download as a new app on the user device?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, info.plist

If the bundle display name is changed in a future version of an already submitted app, does it  download as a completely different app on the user's device or does the display name simply change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The display name will just change. The bundle ID is what determines if a new app will be installed.